# how to assign lines of variable length to a variable in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a file I want to read that has a variable number of ids for each location that looks like this:

```
loc1    id1    id4    id5   id9
loc2    id2 
loc3    id1    id11   id23
```

I would like to store this as follows locs(loc) = {all ids belonging to that location} 
So that later, when I read another file I can do something like

```
if (grep id, locs(loc)){do something}
```

I tried to do this using a hash, but this is not working. I tried:

```
open my $loclist, '<', $ARGV[0];
my %locs;
while (<$loclist>) {
my @loclist_rec = split;
my $loclist_loc = @rlist_rec[0];
$locs{$loclist_loc} = @loclist_rec;
}
```

but this isnt working. 
I new to perl and still trying to understand the different datatypes.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to learn the difference between arrays and arrayrefs.  All you need to do is `$locs{$loclist_loc} = \@loclist_rec;` to put a _reference_ to the array into the hash value.

Comment: Everyone is giving you an answer using [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). What you need is the [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). References are great when you have Arrays of Arrays, or Hashes of Arrays of Hashes. Or any sort of complex structure that doesn't fit neatly into Perl's original three variable types. Read the tutorial, and all will become clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the tutorial! Thats just what I need :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $loclist, '<', "test.txt" or die $!;
my %locs;

while (<$loclist>) {
    my ($loclist_loc, @loclist_rec) = split;
    $locs{$loclist_loc} = \@loclist_rec;
}

print Dumper \%locs;
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ perl test.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'loc2' => [
                      'id2'
                    ],
          'loc1' => [
                      'id1',
                      'id4',
                      'id5',
                      'id9'
                    ],
          'loc3' => [
                      'id1',
                      'id11',
                      'id23'
                    ]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a possible choice would be a hash of hashes. When you want to look up an id, you could say `if ($locs{$loc}{$id}) {do something}`. The data structure would be

```
$VAR1 = {
          'loc2' => {
                      'id2' => 1
                    },
          'loc1' => {
                      'id1' => 1,
                      'id5' => 1,
                      'id4' => 1,
                      'id9' => 1
                    },
          'loc3' => {
                      'id1' => 1,
                      'id11' => 1,
                      'id23' => 1
                    }
        };
```